# Error if execution time exceeds 30 seconds using Mail::send in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, wampserver, execution-time

I am setting up laravel to send emails. So, I was testing laravel to send 100 emails. Sometimes it works and sometimes it didn't. I noticed that if the time taken to send out those 100 emails is more than 30 seconds then it will fail. But, if it takes less than 30 seconds then it will successfully send all the 100 emails out.

```
class EmailController extends BaseController
{
    public function sendMail()
    {
            //user_json is data retrived from json    
            $users_json = 'json_input';    
            $users = json_decode($users_json, true);

            foreach($users as $user)
            {
                Mail::send('message', $user, function($message) use ($user)
                {
                    $message->to($user['email'], $user['first_name'])
                            ->subject('Laravel Email Test');
                });

            }       
    }
}
```

I used wamp with my laravel. I have increased the execution limit in php.ini file in wamp.

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 1024M
```

The email send still fails if it exceeds 30 seconds. Is there another php.ini file (in laravel) I should change to increase the limit? Is there a better way to optimise this Mail:send as I might need to send 100k emails daily?

Comment: Please create a PHP file in your Webroot path and call the PHP function "<?php phpinfo; ?>" to check if your changes in the php.ini are set correctly.

Comment: @xyNNN WampServer comes with a link to phpinfo() on the WAMPServr home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 php.ini files in WAMPServer like many Apache/PHP instances.

Make sure you are using the WAMPManager icon menus to edit the one that is used by Apache.

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

The other one lives in `\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\php.ini` and is used when you run PHP CLI (Command Line Interface)